# Best practices for accessing methods of one class from methods of another class

Tags: java, methods

So we have this class `class Identity` and also a  `class CanineCommunication`

then if we want to define a class

```
class Dog {
    public Dog() {
        Identity id;
        CanineCommunication cc;
    }
    id.getParticulars(); //we can call all the public Identity methods
    cc.getMoves(); //and also the public CanineCommunication methods
}
```

But assuming the methods in the class CanineCommunication require the use of Identity methods - one obvious way to do it would be:

```
class CanineCommunication {
    getNoises(Identity id) {
        id.getParticulars();
        //~~if small be squeaky &c~~
    }
```

Another way would be:

```
class CanineCommunication {
    Identity id;
    public canineCommunication (Identity id) {
         this.id=id;
    }
    getNoises() {
        id.getParticulars();
        //~~if small be squeaky &c~~
    }
```

How do these methods compare? And are there any other (better/worse) ways to achieve this?

Comment: This code really doesn't make much sense, even beyond the fact that you're not capitalizing `CanineCommunication`. What are you trying to do here? The "best way" to handle this will depend very much on how the dependencies between the classes work logically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what your design is : 
In the case where you are passing Identity object to constructor, you are working on a single instance of Identity and you might need to take care of any static variables or threas unsafe variables

In the case where you pass Identity object everytime you are in a similar sitiuation as above if you pass the same object but you have the flexibility to pass new object everytime

More or less it depends on your requirement

Answer (score 0):

If your `CanineCommunication` instance works only with one `Identity` then the second approach would be better. So each `CanineCommunication` has its own `Identity` and works exclusively with this `Identity`.

If your `CanineCommunication#getNoises` method should work with different Identities then the first approach would be better.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a matter of relation: where does the `noise` belong to? Is `bark` a property of `Dog` or does `Dog` use `doBark` from the SoundSystem?

The "correct" implementation always depends on your actual code. For example it might be better to have a SoundSystem implementation to make sure actual wave files are not duplicated in memory and to limit access to the sound channels. Because in this case the "sound" is (as a resource in memory) related to a resource manager.

But if you have some lightweight way of communication and the "sound" is nothing but a single String, then it might be easier to have something like `myDog.bark()`.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, i would use enums to modle the caninccommunication. Then a dog would have a list of type CanineCommunication.

And a small dog would be a class that extends your class dog and automaticly has a squeky canine communication in his list.

you could then do something like this:

```
for(Dog myDog : myDogs)
{
   if(myDog.getCanineCommunications().contains(CanineCommunication.SQUEKY))
   {
     myDog.doSomething();
   }
}
```